# Problem with document.querySelectorAll and a for loop

Tags: javascript

On this web page, https://editart2020.crooked.media/collection/fundamentos/, mouse over the first image to see the caption -- it has a comma and the word "by".

I got that with this simple code:

```
    const caption = document.querySelector('.ae-overlay-caption').innerHTML;
    caption2 = caption.replace("<br>",",<br>by ");
    document.querySelector('.ae-overlay-caption').innerHTML = caption2;
```

Now when I try to get the other captions to work, I tried this code:

```
const captions = document.querySelectorAll('.ae-overlay-caption').innerHTML;
    for (var i; i < captions.length; i++) {
        caption[i] = captions.replace("<br>",",<br>by ");
        document.querySelector('.ae-overlay-caption').innerHTML = caption[i];
    }
```

However, the console says that captions is not defined.  I don't know why and I've tried many variations of this code, and different for loops, to no avail. Thanks.

Comment: An element will have an `innerHTML` property, a collection of elements won't.

Comment: The same problem anyone has that comes from a jQuery background.

Comment: So how do I get the others?

Comment: should be `caption[i] = captions[i].replace("<br>",",<br>by ");`... where is caption comming from?

Comment: If I change the code to this:

const captions = document.querySelectorAll('.ae-overlay-caption');
    for (var i; i < captions.length; i++) {
        caption = caption[i].replace("<br>",",<br>by ");
        document.querySelector('.ae-overlay-caption').innerHTML = caption;
    }
I still only get the first one.

Comment: const captions = document.querySelectorAll('.ae-overlay-caption');
    console.log(captions);
    for (var i; i < captions.length; i++) {
        caption = caption[i].replace("<br>",",<br>by ");
        document.querySelector('.ae-overlay-caption').innerHTML = caption;
    }

Comment: I still only get the first caption